# Does sending raw data in Sinatra in URL params present an XSS issue?

Tags: backbone.js, parameters, sinatra, xss

I'm running an app with Sinatra/backbone.

Let's say I visit the page `http://localhost:3000/cases/1/read?name=Some%20Guy` that is using the `name` parameter to display data on the page.

Does this present an XSS issue?

I'm just trying to send data from one page to another through a button click with the param data.

Comment: Need any further info? If so I'll update my answer.

Comment: No, I think your answer is good for now. I didn't end up using a URL param. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test is to try the URL

```
http://localhost:3000/cases/1/read?name=<script>alert('foo');</script>
```

If the script executes and an alert popup appears, then XSS is definitely possible.

Other [XSS patterns are possible too](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) depending on where the `name` value is output.

You should [output encode](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) to prevent this type of attack. The encoding to use depends on the language context of your output (if is it JavaScript, HTML, or CSS, etc). e.g. `"` becomes `&quot;` in HTML, but `\x22` in JavaScript and JSON. The correct encoding prevents an attacker being able to escape out of the context and inject their own scripts. You should also set the charset to UTF-8 to prevent some [UTF-7 filter evasion attacks](http://openmya.hacker.jp/hasegawa/security/utf7cs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary. All dependence on which way data shows to user. If you keep in mind, that data can be wrong and for example  escape string before output - it will be ok.